# What is the difference between sovereign bond and government bond?

Tags: bond

what is the difference between sovereign bond and government bond? Can I assume that both are the same? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Yes they are the same. "sovereign" is a little bit clearer in that it makes it explicit it may be a foreign government that issues, not necessarily my own government . But it is not used as often so it sounds a little pedantic or academic, like you are showing off your erudition.

Comment: Also "sovereign" explicitly includes emerging market government debt issued in another currency (like USD or EUR) instead of the native currency. It is not clear when you say "government bonds" whether these are intended to be included or whether you are talking only of domestic currency gov bonds So again, more precise to use "sovereign".